# Display real time data on website that scales?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, scalability, azure-functions

I am starting a project where I want to create a website which will display LIVE flight information and status. We all have seen this at airport. An example is given here - http://www.computronics.biz/productimages/prodairport4.jpg. As you can see this information **changes continuously**. The website will talk to a backend api and the this backend api will talk to **database**. Now the important part is that the flight information in the **database** will be updated by the airline itself. There could be several airlines and they will update their data respectively. I have drawn a diagram and uploaded here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/u44Bm.jpg.

Now those airlines will obviously have an interface (website talking to some backend API) through which they will update the database.

Now here is my attempt to solve it. We need to have some sort of trigger such that if any airline updates a flight detail in the database between current time - 1 hour to current + 4 hours (website will only display few hours of flights), we need to call the web api and then send the update to the website in the real time. **The user must not refresh the page at all.** At the same time the website needs to scale well i.e. if 1 million users are on the website, and there is an update in the database in the correct time range, all 1 million user's website should get updated within a decent amount of time.

I did some research and it looks like we need to have an event based approach. For example - we need to create a function (AWS lambda or Azure function) that should be called whenever there is an update in the database (Dynamo DB for example) within the correct time range. This function then should call an API which should then update the website through web socket technology for example.

I am not looking for any code but just some alternative suggestions on how this can be solved in a scalable way. Also how do we test scalability?

Comment: Ready. Fire. Aim.

Comment: Do the airlines need to update the database directly or can it be abstracted through an API that airlines invoke?

Comment: @dashmug - haha true :)

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil - they will have an user interface which will talk to an API and the that API will update some DB (sql server, dynamo db) etc.

Comment: @VVV I see. I just posted a high level solution with a section on scalability testing with my central theme being you don't need lambda or azure functions.

Comment: Have you checked out AWS AppSync: https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/

Comment: @Richard - thanks, no i have never heard of it. Let me have a look.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil - thanks, I went through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dont use serverless functions(Lambda/Azure functions)**

Although I am a huge fan of serverless functions, and currently running a full web app in Lambda, I don't think its needed for your use case and doesn't make sense economically. As you've answered in the comments, each airline will not write directly to the database, they'll push to an API, meaning you are explicitly told when flights have changed. When an airline has sent you new data you can simply propagate this to all the browser endpoints via websockets. This keeps the design very simple. There is no need to artificially create a database event that then triggers a function that will then tell you a flight has been updated. Thats like removing your doorbell and replacing it with a motion detector that triggers a doorbell :)

**Cost**

Money always deserves its own section. Lambda is more of an economic break through than a technological one. You have to know when its cost effective. You pay per request so if your dealing with a process that handles 10,000 operations a month, or something that only fires 1,000 times a day, than lambda is dirt cheap and practically free. You also pay for the length of time the function is executing and the memory consumed while executing. Generally, it makes sense to use lambda functions where a dedicated server would be sitting idle for most of the time. So instead of a whole EC2 instance, AWS provides you with a container on demand. There are points at which high requests rates and constantly running processes makes lambda more expensive than EC2. This article discusses how generally its cheaper to use lambda up to a point -> https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-cost/ The same applies to Azure functions and googles equivalent. They are all just containers offered on demand.

If you're dealing with flight information I would imagine you will have thousands of flights being updated every minute so your lambda functions will be firing constantly as if you were running an EC2 instance. You will end up paying a lot more than EC2. When you have a service that needs to stay up 24/7 and run 24/7 with high activity that is most certainly a valid use case for a dedicated server or servers.

**Proposed Solution**

These are the components I would use below:

- Message Queue of some sort (RabbitMQ or AWS SQS with SNS perhaps)
- Web Socket Backend (The choice will depend on programming language)
- Airline input API (REST,GraphQL, or maybe AWS Kinesis Data Firehose)

[image]

The airlines publish their data to a back-end api. The updates are stored on a message queue and the web applicaton that actually displays the results to users, via websockets, reads from the queue.

**Scalability**

For scalability you can run the websocket application on multiple EC2 instances (all reading from the same queuing service) in an autoscaling group, so with extra load more instances will be created automatically hence the name "autoscaling". And those instances can sit behind an elastic load balancer. Lots of AWS documentation on how to do this and its their flagship design pattern. If you use AWS SQS you don't have to manage the scalability details yourself, aws handles that. The only real components to scale are your websocket application and the flight data input endpoint. You can run the flight api in an autoscaling group as well but AWS does offer an additional tool for high traffic data processing. I detail that below.

**Testing Scalability**

It would be fairly easy to have a mock airline blast your service with thousands and thousands of fake updates and on the other end you can easily run multiple threads of selenium tests simulating browser clicks and validating that the UI is still operational.

**Additional tools**

If it ends up being large amounts of data, rather than using a conventional REST api for your flight update service you could consider a service AWS offers specifically for dealing with large amounts of real time updates (Kinessis Data Firehose) https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/ But I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks buddy for the detailed essay. ya the cost is a big factor and my current approach is an overkill. Your solution is very good. You have removed functions and DB and you already have a web app using AWS Lambda function so you obviously know better. My only worry is that because there is no DB, there is no state. Now at this point it looks fine but not sure if I would face any problem when I start implementing it. Thanks a lot for your time though. You probably spent over an hour writing and drawing this :)

Comment: No problem. Its fun to share, this site has helped me a lot in the past as well. You can certainly add a database if you want historical record keeping. The message Queue is a storage mechanism itself but I could definitely see  a future need to scroll back through different posts so a DB could be useful. I only omitted it for simplicity. Glad this helps. Good luck on the project.

Comment: @VVV This is a great answer, but **not for your situation**.  Speaking for experience *with this exact situation*, anything more than a simple database and background client refresh is way, way, way over complicating it.  Note, the queue-> socket approach will not work because the data in't always sequential.

Comment: @Johns-305 AWS SQS offers order control (FIFO). But a queue is not a must.... In regards to websockets, their intended for real-time display. Everywhere websockets are used you can certainly replace them with simple polling but at a price. I don't think linking a table display to a socket on the front-end is a huge complexity sacrifice.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil My main point is that in this case, because of actual on the ground circumstances, the solution is this answer just doesn't fit.  Realistically, how the client updates is maybe 5% of the overall consideration.  To be clear, this stack will work great....for something else. :)  I just don't want OP to spend time on things that they'll realize eventually really don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

First, please don't over think this.  This is a trivial problem to solve and doesn't require any special techniques, technologies or trendy patterns & frameworks.

You actually have three functional areas you can address almost separately.

1. Ingestion - Collection and normalization of the data from the various sources.  For this, you'll need a process and transformation engine, LogicApps or such.
2. Your databases.  You'll quickly learn that not all flights are the same ;).  While it might seem so, the amount of data isn't *that* much.  Instances of MySQL/SQL Server tuned for a particular function will work just fine.  Hint, you don't need to have data for every movement ready to present all the time.
3. Presentation.  The data API and UIs.  This, really, is the easy part.  I would suggest you use basic polling at first.  For reasons you will never have any control over, the SLA for flight data is ~5 minutes so a real-time client notification system is time you should spend elsewhere at first.

Comment: i get point 1, for point 2 you mean we can setup a trigger in SQL server such that whenever there is an update, an Azure function will be called. How will this Azure function update the user website then?

Comment: @VVV There a gazillion callback patterns out there, but I'm saying that in the beginning, you don't need to do this.  The client can poll (in the background) to update itself.  You don't need to be real-time because the data isn't.

Comment: thanks, ya actually it is a over-kill. Problem with client polling is that is 1 million have that website opened, they will send 1 million concurrent requests. So I think I will go with web socket for that.

Comment: @VVV Trust me, you're wasting your time.  It's not reasonable to expect to have 12% of daily passengers *worldwide* using your site.  Maintaining sockets is expensive and unreliable.  Worry about polling performance when you hit 10,000 users.  Believe me, you're waaaayyyy overestimating the need for real-time updates.